# Email/Password Authentication Mongodb-stitch Android API

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

This seems to be on a very new topic because the "stitch" or "mongodb-stitch" tags do not exist yet.

I have a mongodb altas cluster on cloud.mongodb.com.  The page https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/auth/email-auth/ only teaches how to do things with JS but I don't have server side JS on hand.  Instead I tried to figure out how to do things with the StitchClient on the Android API.

I was able to register an email/password pair using StitchClient.register(email,pwd) and got an email from no-reply+stitch@mongodb.com with the token/tokenId.  I copied them and used StitchClient.emailConfirm(token, tokenId) but failed.  The error was:

```
Unexpected response code 404 for https://stitch.mongodb.com/api/client/v1.0/app/APP-ID/auth/local/userpass/confirm
```

which sounds strange!  I opened a browser and paste that in the URL and got 404 too.  I even did

```
curl --data "token=432...345&tokenId=435..334" https://stitch.mongodb.com/api/client/v1.0/app/APP-ID/auth/local/userpass/confirm
```

and still got 404.

Is this a bug or an outage of the stitch.mongodb.com server?

Comment: Tag added. Synopsis coming.

Comment: Service seems to be working as far as I can see. Not sure where you are getting that URL from. There is actually a "Getting Started" section on the console for any App you create with Stitch. This has a section with "Execute a Test Request" in which you can basically get generated code for 4 different platforms for a complete test application. There's also a [number of guides](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/tutorials/). But the "first" thing you should be doing is following that "Execute a Test Request" code and running that. Then you can start playing with other things.

Comment: I have "Executed a test request" all right.  In fact I could do StitchClient.register(email,pwd) several times, but only failed when I ran StitchClient.emailConfirm().  From hindsight I noticed that the android client I am using has logged in anonymously.  I do not know whether such a user has the privilege to confirm an email/user.  The URL I got it from the android log spit out as an Exception for the 404 response.

Comment: Sounds more like you still need to read some more guides. [Email/Password Authentication is described in the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/auth/email-auth/). And generally requires a callback URL in your own hosted application, allowing a client to open a browser and enter, then redirect. You probably want ["Custom Authentication"](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/auth/custom-auth/). Questions here really should have more complete code at least following the guides in a way that can be reproduced. The "how to's" are essentially in the documentation.

Comment: I have tried to use "my own hosted application" and got a 400 response.  I'll post my findings as another question (php code involved) when I have a more convenient computer with me.

Comment: I was able to use JS now but still have problems, which is given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352830/expired-token-for-email-password-authentication-using-mongodb-stitch-js-api