# Expired token for Email/Password Authentication using Mongodb-stitch JS API

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I have a mongodb altas cluster on cloud.mongodb.com.

As per the instructions in https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/auth/email-auth/ I was able to register an email/password pair.  About 12 hours later I received the confirmation email.  I visited the link in the confirmation email yet 12 hours later.  Chrome browser developer tools tells me that the server returned HTTP 400 and body:

```
{"error": "the token is expired or invalid"}
```

I think the token has expired, but when I tried to register the same email again,  the server returned HTTP 409 and body:

```
{"error": "name already in use"}
```

So if the token expires, is there a way I can register it again?

Comment: try to reset password.

Comment: Yes, it works.  Thanks.  If you post this answer I will accept it.